# How to test for presence of Tobacco/nicotine in a product?

Tags: toxicity, identification

I found this [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3263647/) that says nicotine was found in major toothpaste brands in India. Rather than playing blame game, wouldn't it be easier to test ourselves ?

How to test for presence of Tobacco/nicotine in a product ?

Comment: The paper states how they did it (extraction followed by GC/MS), so that method should work.

Comment: I was hoping for something that does not required a GC/MS..but if there was a cheaper/easier way, they wouldn't have gone for a costlier method .. hmmm :(

Comment: The problem is that you need to isolate the nicotine from the mess.  GC does this automagically, and when piped into the MS, you can know the identity of the product because the 70eV ei fingerprint for nicotine is characteristic of that compound (well any compound).  Other tests would be ether be less reliable or much more laborious.